# Update multiple rows in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I want to be able to update multiple rows in a column using a unique value for each unique row. I.E I want to take a value from another table for a person and use that to replace a password and I want to be able to do that in bulk

I have code below.

```
Update PERSON

Set Person.PASSWD = CONTPOINT.FILEAS From CONTPOINT INNER JOIN PERSON on Person.SERIALNO = CONTPOINT.SERIALNO

WHERE CONTPOINT.CPTYPENO = 3 AND Person.SERIALNO in ('45822', '44281', '28241', '28241', '31415', '31415', '31415', '31415', '31415', '39318', '41677', '41681', '41682', '41683', '45604', '45604', '45713', '45807', '45807', '45822', '45822', '45822', '32808', '27435', '17665', '30109', '27111', '27111', '43114', '43114', '39097', '39097', '43574', '40114', '30787', '30787', '39096', '39095', '39095', '27137', '27135', '22003', '27135', '33532', '27136', '27134', '33532', '34085', '27134', '17515', '26152', '26152', '26152', '26152', '26152', '26152', '34902', '42296', '34903', '40538', '41599', '41599', '29586', '42236', '29585', '10436', '43119', '38967', '37942', '10625', '10625', '43580', '43580', '43579', '43579', '45386', '30838', '30838', '30838', '30838', '30838', '30838', '30838', '30838', '30838', '30842', '30842', '30841', '30841', '30841', '30841', '30841', '30841', '23488', '24142', '24142', '24142', '24142', '41358', '41358', '41358', '41358', '39538', '39538', '39538', '39538', '4280', '4280', '4280', '4280', '4280', '4280', '39353', '39352', '43758', '8134', '43758', '35447', '8135', '35447', '41019', '41019', '41019', '41019', '33624', '41107', '33624', '38185', '34810', '34810', '34810', '34810', '34810', '34810', '34030', '34289', '34289', '34289', '34289', '34289', '34289', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21760', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '21508', '43980', '21509', '21509', '13229', '13229', '13229', '13229', '13229', '13229', '41932', '42585', '44781', '38865', '30354', '30354', '33307', '45397', '44752', '42731', '43490', '25466', '25466', '25466', '25466', '25466', '25466', '24230', '39453', '39453', '39453', '39453', '34522', '41595', '41595', '41595', '41594')
```

Comment: What is wrong with the query you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
UPDATE P
SET P.PASSWD = C.FILEAS
FROM Person P
JOIN CONTPOINT C ON P.SERIALNO = C.SERIALNO
WHERE ...
```

Your question is a little confusing, you should add what the problem with your current query is in the future. (including any error messages)

Comment: When I want to use multiple serialno's which are essentially the unique id's of the users i get error:
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 3
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @jchris151 That means there is a `C.FILEAS` that is too large to fit into `P.PASSWD`

Comment: Ik, i figured, is there anyway to ignore it?

Comment: @jchris151 You have 2 options: A. Increase the size of the `PASSWD` field so that all `C.FILEAS` values can fit, or B. Only take the maximum number of characters from the `C.FILEAS` that will fit.  (example, using 8 as the max size of `PASSWD`: `SET P.PASSWD = LEFT(C.FILEAS,8)`).  Usually you would want to do the top option you aren't cutting of the data, but the bottom works if it doesn't matter that the data is being truncated.